# Remove Kernel Lock from Unmounted Mass Storage USB Device from the Command Line in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, mount, camera

I've searched high and low, and can't figure this one out. I have a older Olympus Camera (2001 or so). When I plug in the USB connection, I get the following log output:

```
$ dmesg | grep sd
[20047.625076] sd 21:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[20047.627922] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Secondly, the drive is not mounted in the FS, but when I run gphoto2 I get the following error:

```
$ gphoto2 --list-config

*** Error ***              
An error occurred in the io-library ('Could not lock the device'): Camera is already in use.
*** Error (-60: 'Could not lock the device') ***
```

What command will unmount the drive. For example in Nautilus, I can right click and select "Safely Remove Device". After doing that, the /dev/sg7 and /dev/sdg devices are removed.

The output of gphoto2 is then:

```
# gphoto2 --list-config
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/resolution                              
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/shutter
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/aperture
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/color
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/flash
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/whitebalance
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/focus-mode
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/focus-pos
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/exp
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/exp-meter
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/zoom
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/dzoom
/Camera Configuration/Picture Settings/iso
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/date-time
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/lcd-mode
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/lcd-brightness
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/lcd-auto-shutoff
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/camera-power-save
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/host-power-save
/Camera Configuration/Camera Settings/timefmt
```

Some things I've tried already are `sdparm` and `sg3_utils`, however I am unfamiliar with them, so it's possible I just didn't find the right command.

**Update 1:**

```
# mount | grep sdg
# mount | grep sg7
# umount /dev/sg7
umount: /dev/sg7: not mounted
# umount /dev/sdg
umount: /dev/sdg: not mounted
# gphoto2 --list-config

*** Error ***              
An error occurred in the io-library ('Could not lock the device'): Camera is already in use.
*** Error (-60: 'Could not lock the device') ***
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, `gphoto2` only deals with MTP/PTP devices, not mass storage...

Comment: sorry, maybe my terminology is off, but it work when I unmount from Nautilus

Comment: no solution so far, any ideas?

Comment: gvfs-mount doesn't work then? (see my answer)

Comment: Peter Janic's solution worked great for me. A ptp mounted device does not show up with the "mount" command, but "gvfs-mount -l" and "gvfs-mount -u" do work on my ptp mounted nikon d70. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick and Dirty Method

For a brute force disable of all active mass storage devices:

```
rmmod usb_storage
```

## Prevent Any Device from Loading usb_storage Module

I found the following link, basically asking [the same question as this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/how-to-unclaim-usb-device-558138/). If you want to prevent the kernel from auto-mounting using `usb_storage`:

```
echo "blacklist usb_storage" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-usb-storage.conf
```

## Prevent Single Device from Loading usb_storage Module

Instead of disabling all devices, you can target a specific device to ignore using udev rules. There is a specific example [here](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html%23example-camera).

I spent a lot of time trying to get this to work in Ubuntu 10.04, but it looks like this functionality [was disabled in newer versions of udev](http://www.spinics.net/lists/hotplug/msg03258.html).

## "Safely Remove Disk" Unbind/Unclaim Source Code

The [last post on this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/how-to-unclaim-usb-device-558138/) worked like a charm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   struct usbdevfs_ioctl command;
   int ret;
   int fd;
   int i;
   if (argc>1) {
      fd = open(argv[1],O_RDWR);
      if (fd<1){
         perror("unable to open file");
         return 1;
      }
      for (i=0;i<255;i++){ // hack: should fetch how many interface there is.
         command.ifno = i;
         command.ioctl_code = USBDEVFS_DISCONNECT;
         command.data = NULL;
         ret = ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_IOCTL, &command);
         if(ret!=-1)
            printf("un claimed interface %d %d\n",i,ret);
      }
   }else {
      printf ("usage: %s /dev/bus/usb/BUS/DEVICE\n",argv[0]);
      printf("Release all interfaces of this usb device for usage in virtualisation\n");
   }
}
```

## Simple Script for Binding / Unbinding Device

The previous example is an interesting case, but I also found a much simplified method. You can use the [usb-storage driver interface for binding and unbinding devices](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/).

The following command worked, just like the source code from above:

```
echo -n "1-2.4:1.0" | sudo tee unbind
```

Answer (score 0):

First, run `mount` as root. This should list all mounted filesystems. If `/dev/sdg` and `/dev/sg7` are not in the list, then the camera is no longer mounted.

If the camera is still mounted, you can unmount it with the command `umount` (note the missing 'n'). An example would be `umount /dev/sg7` or `umount /dev/sdg`.

If the camera has mounted filesystems, then you can probably just browse to the photos in Nautilus. The output of `mount` will tell you where the devices are mounted to in the filesystem - just browse to the folder and start looking around for the photos.

Comment: I added the output of the commands in the question .. I'm sure I tried that a few days ago ;)

Comment: Also, you assume I am trying to download photos, that is not the case.

Comment: @casey: **/dev/sg7** wouldn't have been mounted anyway -- that's a scsi control device, not a drive.  **/dev/sdg** might be a mountable device, and might be a partitioned drive (in which case you'd have to mount **/dev/sdg1** or **/dev/sdg2** or similar).

Comment: There are no partitions shown on /dev/sdg

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu? There is [talk](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-965167.html) of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/285682) in 8.10, and while I'm not sure if this is fixed in the latest version, there is a [workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6161390#post6161390) which might let you do... whatever it is you're trying to do (since you aren't just downloading pictures). :P

Comment: It looks similar, but I can get gphoto to work if I simply unmount the device from Nautilus first. I'll make sure to read it all and try and of the workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in a script:

```
# If camera is mounted we need to unmount it
export CAMERA_MOUNT_POINTS=`gvfs-mount -l | grep gphoto2 | sed 's/.*\(gphoto2.*\)$/\1/' | uniq 2> $LOG_FILE`
for CAMERA_MOUNT_POINT in $CAMERA_MOUNT_POINTS
do
    echo Unmounting mounted camera from $CAMERA_MOUNT_POINT.
    gvfs-mount -u $CAMERA_MOUNT_POINT &> $LOG_FILE
done
```

I am not sure this is what you need, but it might be, since I've had similar problems.

EDIT:
To explain a little:
`gvfs-mount -l` lists mounted stuff
The rest of that line cleans the output to produce just a list of mounted cameras (and pipes errors to a log file).
Then the loop unmounts all cameras.

Comment: I changed something, and now gvfs_mount does not list the device. I'll try again after a reboot.

Comment: It didn't work then, I guess, since you pursued another line?